# PHP Grab HTML Tag Rows/Hierarchy

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-lists

So I wanted to know if there was a way to grab a specific HTML tag's information using PHP.

Let's say we had this code:

```
<ul>
<li>First List</li>
<li>Second List</li>
<li>Third List</li>
</ul>
```

How could I search the HTML and pull the third list item's value into a variable? Or is there a way you could pull the entire unordered list into an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Has not been tested or compiled, but one way is create a function that utilizes [**PHP: DOMDocument**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) and its method [**`getElementsByTagName`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) which returns a 
[**PHP: DOMNodeList**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) that you can access the node at a specific index.

```
function grabAttributes($file, $tag, $index) {
 $dom = new DOMDocument();
 if (!@$dom->load($file)) {
   echo $file . " doesn't exist!\n";
   return;
 }

 $list = $dom->getElementsByTagName($tag); // returns DOMNodeList of given tag
 $newElement = $list->item($index)->nodeValue; // initialize variable 
 return $newElement;
}
```

If you call `grabAttributes("myfile.html", "li", 2)` the variable will be set to `"Third List"`

Or you can make a function to put all the attributes of a given tag into an array.

```
function putAttributes($file, $tag) {
$dom = new DOMDocument();
if (!@$dom->load($file)) {
  echo $file . " doesn't exist!\n";
  return;
}

$list = $dom->getElementsByTagName($tag); // returns DOMNodeList of given tag
$myArray = array(); // array to contain values.
foreach ($list as $tag) { // loop through node list and add to an array.
    $myArray[] = $tag->nodeValue;
 } 

   return $myArray;
}
```

If you call `putAttributes("myfile.html", "li")` it would return `array("First List", "Second List", "Third List")`

Comment: It didn't work. Using grabAttributes I got this error:

Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string in

Comment: Try `li` instead of `"li"`, also editing the code, I think what I wanted was `$list->item($index)->nodeValue`